# Load Balancing - Does it share MySQL Max Connections or grant more?

Tags: mysql, nginx, load, load-balancing, mariadb

Quick question about load balancers. If MySQL allows 100 max connections and then I add a load balancer with another VPS, does I still only have 100 max connections or do I not have 200. Depending on the method of balancing the load of course. Will I have over 100 or still just 100?

Comment: If you are hitting 100, you have other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to balance if you have **one** MySQL server, so all you're adding is overhead.
If we should read your question as:

> If I add another MySQL server and put a load balancer in front

Then the answer is, you will have 100 + whatever you configure on the second MySQL server or the number of connections the load balancer can handle - whichever is lower.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the 100 limit in mysql config, then that limit is independent of the load balancer.